# Delete Shadow Copies Remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, wmi, vss

I currently use `DISKSHADOW` to remove shadow copies from our Hyper-V servers. To do this I have to log onto the server but `psexec`  doesn't work.

```
psexec \\hyper-v-server diskshadow
DISKSHADOW> Error reading from console. Win32 error: 0x6
The handle is invalid.
```

I think `vssadmin` works doing the above, but I'd like to script this with PowerShell and slectively remove the shadow copies. Neither of these tools provide usable output in PowerShell.

I've done a bit of research but not found any way to query snapshots with PowerShell, either locally or remotely. I imagine doing this will involve use of the `Get-WMIObject` CMDlet to query the relevant info from WMI, but I can only find the `Win32_ShadowCopy.Create()` method.

**EDIT:** To be clear, what I would like are objects I can manipulate using PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Get-WMIObject cmdlet to remotely remove shadow copies. The example below demonstrates how it might work. It should be noted that the Get-WMIObject cmdlet returned a null object in the case where there were not any remote shadow copies available. This means that might still need a combination of PowerShell remoting and the vssadmin tool to remotely create shadow copies.

On the target server (from an elevated command prompt), let's first create a shadow copy so that one is available:

```
vssadmin create shadow /for=c:
```

From the management server:

```
$shadowCopies = Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_ShadowCopy -Computer <TARGET SERVER NAME>
$shadowCopies | % {$_.DeviceObject}  # Lists out just the names of the copies
$shadowCopies | Get-Member -View All # Lists all members even hidden ones such as "delete"
$shadowCopies[0].Delete()            # Deletes the first shadow copy when more than one exists
$shadowCopies.Delete()               # Works when only a single shadow copy exists
```

Comment: It looks perfect. I didn't see the Delete() method listed in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394428(v=vs.85).aspx. Presumably this method is inherited from somewhere?

Comment: +1.  I was exploring the very same path as @tchester, when `$shadowCopies[0] | Get-Member -Force` did not contain `.Delete()` I started looking elsewhere.  This is a great answer, I'd love to here where `.Delete()` is inherited from and why it's not "shown".

Comment: I see now. `$shadowCopies[0].GetType()` is [ManagementObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Management.ManagementObject.aspx), which does provide `.Delete()` -- still not sure why it wouldn't be shown with `Get-Member`.

Comment: One more try: `$shadowCopies[0] | Get-Member -Force -View All` will show `.Delete()`.  Guess you learn something new everyday. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this remotely with diskshadow. To accomplish this, write a batch file containing the wanted commands and place it somewhere on the target server, then: `psexec \\remotehost diskshadow /s C:\path\to\script.bat`. You can also use a network location for the path.

Comment: Thanks @NathanC. I was aware of this also, but I don't like the idea of having to maintain the batch files on each of our hosts. It just feels a bit "hacky".

Comment: You can specify a remote path so you only have to have a single batch file.